# toggleClass and executed order in a jquery file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The jquery trigger into entered status when mouse move in.

```js
$(".test").bind("mouseenter mouseout", function(event) {
  $(this).toggleClass("entered");
  alert("mouse postion (" + event.pageX + "," + event.pageY + ")");
});
```

```css
.entered {
  font-size: 36px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.test {
  border: 2px solid red;
  background: #fdd;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test">please move in</div>
```

I found that two issues in my code snippet.

1. For the entered status ,only `font-size:36px;` take effect,why  `width:200px;height:100px;border:2px solid black;` take no effect?
2. `alert` pop up before `$(this).toggleClass("entered");` is completed,how to make `alert` execute after `$(this).toggleClass("entered");` is totally completed?

Comment: Your fiddle was broken as it did not include jQuery, so I added it for you.

Comment: You might want to look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38391178/jquery-toggleclass-callback-how-to

Comment: The problem seems pretty moot anyway, as you really shouldn't be using `alert()` for this. Use `console.log`

Comment: for the first problem, just switch position of the two css statements

Comment: "*alert pop up before $(this).toggleClass("entered"); is completed,*" No, it doesn't. What happens is that the js execution has been blocked by alert before the browser entered the paint phase. So some browser (Chrome?) will not enter this paint phase. Some others (e.g Firefox) will anyway. But in all, toggleClass which is synchronous will have been executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. This is because of selector precedence. `.test` is the last rule in the stylesheet which affects that element and it overrides the previous styles. To fix this, put the `.entered` rule last, and prefix it with `.test`.

   Here's a good guide on how CSS selector specificity works from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity).
2. This is because `alert()` blocks the UI thread from updating until its dismissed. This is one of the reasons you shouldn't use it. You could use a `setTimeout()` call to delay the `alert()`, but a much better and approrpriate solution is to just use `console.log()` instead.

Also note that `bind()` is now deprecated and will be removed from the latest versions of jQuery. You should be using [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on) instead.

```js
$(".test").on("mouseenter mouseout", function(event) {
  $(this).toggleClass("entered");
  console.log("mouse postion (" + event.pageX + "," + event.pageY + ")");
});
```

```css
.test {
  border: 2px solid red;
  background-color: #fdd;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
}

.test.entered {
  font-size: 36px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test">please move in</div>
```

Comment: Note that it is not specified anywhere that `alert` should "block the UI thread".   It should block the js thread, but some browsers don't block the UI thread.